# Gerar página de dados JSON no Jekyll

Tags: ajax, json, jekyll

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de gerar uma página com dados em `JSON` (dados falsos) no [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com).

O intuito é simular uma requisição `AJAX` para essa página já preparando o código para quando os dados forem gerados pela plataforma vindos de um banco de dados real.

Answer (score 0):

Após algum tempo de pesquisa descobri os [`data files`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) do Jekyll, a princípio pensei que fosse possível ler aqueles dados apenas por meio de templates `liquid`, mas depois de fazer alguns testes notei que a pasta `_data/` também é enviada para a paste `_site/` após o código ser compilado.

Portanto basta fazer uma requisição para o arquivo criado dentro da pasta `_data/`

Exemplo:

```
$.get('data/example.json', function(data) {
    console.info(data);
});
```